statisticalDiagram not plotting estimates
I'm trying to plot the results of my moderated mediation using the statisticalDiagram from processR package. However, only 1 coefficient out of 7 is plotted.
Here is my code:
moderator=list(name="expgroup_cat",site=list(c("a","c")))
model=tripleEquation(X="var4",M="all_watched_after",Y="var_8",moderator=moderator)
semfit=sem(model=model,data=data_full)
statisticalDiagram(8, labels=labels, 
                   arrowlabel = TRUE,
                   fit=semfit, whatLabel ="est",
                   digits=3)

Here is the output table:

And here is the plot, where only path B is labelled.

How can I add all coefficients?
When I opt for whatLabel ="name", everything was labelled.

